# Easy CSS fix bugs (yet still need help)

Tags: css

Ok I got 2 css ones for you

1. check out this link here: http://benjaminpotter.org/clients/c3carlingford/?page_id=61
   notice how the sidebar is all the way down the bottom? How can I get it to sit in the top right and have the text wrap around it?
2. Have a look at the homepage: http://benjaminpotter.org/clients/c3carlingford/ now if you make the browser fill the screen like I do (1680x1050) the footer seems to gain an extra hundred or so pxls? 
   Here is my proof:
   [image]

but when the browser is smaller, there is no problem... again no idea why,

Well thanks again for the help! You lot are a great bunch <3

Answer (score 2):

issue #1 - Put sidebar element right under the header, change margin to `margin: 0 20px 0 0` and you will get what you want. Then adjust position of the tag and margin to get the desired look.

Comment: that was great for number 1, do you know why everything within the sidebar is moved to the right? I can't see the issue: http://benjaminpotter.org/clients/c3carlingford/?page_id=61

Comment: Attache screenshot please as I see it normally. Still looking for solution for #2. Seems like your XHTML html/body are smaller than browser size. This is definitely DTD related.

Comment: Can't find direct solution on #2, sorry. Maybe others can help.

Comment: what do you mean by dtd related?

Comment: I mean you're using XHTML in your Document Type Definition (DTD). If you change doctype, you will get different results as elements are treated differently depending on DTD.